# Storing array in session and retrienving desired value

Tags: php, arrays, session

The code below stores array of post id's into session and using foreach I iterate over post id and call data(title,body) related to that post id. It works fine.

index.php

```
$result = $query->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_COLUMN, 0);
$_SESSION['postid']=$result;
foreach($_SESSION['postid'] as $key=>$postid){
 $sql = "SELECT * FROM posts WHERE postid=:postid";
 $query = $db->prepare($sql);
 $query->execute(array(':postid'=>$postid));
 $row = $query->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
 <a href="post.php"><?php echo $row['title']; ?></a>
 <p><?php echo row['body'] ?></p>
}
```

Now I want to get directed to post page by clicking on `title` link from index page, and call that specific post id from session array whose title was clicked. Using `$postid = $_SESSION['postid'];` on post page gives the whole array of post id's . Is there any way by which I can start session on post page for only that specific post id whose title was clicked on index page.

Comment: Try `<a href="post.php&postid=" . $postId><?php echo $row['title']; ?></a>
 <p><?php echo row['body'] ?></p>`

Answer (score 0):

In index.php page, modify the anchor tag like this :

```
<a href="post.php?pistid='<?php echo $row['postid']; ?>'"><?php echo $row['title']; ?></a>
```

then on post page use this code to set postid in session

```
<?php
$_SESSION['pid'] = isset($_GET['pistid'])$_GET['pistid']:null?;
?>
```

Comment: thanks, was using the same but lot of people tell not to send sensitive data through url and only use session for that.

Comment: yes. you  are right but I don't think the postid is sensitive data. Am I correct?

Comment: yes, but may be sensitive where u let users posts hard written blogs or something like that, url method is fast n easy but m searching something secure like sessions.